# Visual Studio Command Prompt in Visual C# Express?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c#-express-2010

Can I use `Visual Studio Command Prompt` with the free Visual C# Express?

The `Visual Studio Command Prompt` is referenced [here](https://github.com/blak3r/openop/blob/master/CSShellExtContextMenuHandler/ReadMe.txt#L108):

> Run 'Visual Studio Command Prompt (2010)' (or 'Visual Studio x64 Win64 Command Prompt (2010)' if you are on a x64 operating system) in the Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 \
>   Visual Studio Tools menu as administrator.

An unreferenced forum [post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/Vsexpressvb/thread/9f4b8961-63eb-4062-bf3c-12f0126f0e80/) claims it is not available in Express, and lives in `\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\VC\vcvarsall.bat`. The bat file name suggests it may just open a command prompt or PowerShell with a few environment variables, so maybe it is easy to reproduce even without the expensive Visual Studio?

Comment: The following link should solve your problems: -

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4245282/how-can-i-add-the-vs-command-prompt-to-visual-studio-2010-c-sharp-express

Comment: @chrisw69: I vote to close my question as duplicate of that one. Incredible that Google has zero result for: "Visual Studio Command Prompt" "Visual C# Express"

Answer (score 0):

I think you are talking about compiler, C# compiler, is available in few versions with Reddistributables,

refer this link fro beginner that will help you understand better, Search for compiler/redistributable package of .net framework, that will help

```
http://cscsharp.cs.uvic.ca/installCSharp.shtml
```

this will solve your question.