# create a new DLL COM Interop file (.NET Framework 3.5)

Tags: .net, dll, com-interop

I am trying to use Wacom SDK to interact from app VB.NET 2008 with Wacom Tablet (model STU).

In the instructions they say this:

> 1. Build the solution - this will result in errors because of the TLBIMP issue
> 2. Use this DOS command to create a new wgssSTU.dll COM Interop file in the current folder (e.g. DemoButtons\bin\Debug):
>
>    .NET 3.5:     tlbimp /noclassmembers /transform:dispret sourcepath\wgssSTU.dll /out:wgssSTU.tlb.dll
>
>    .NET 4:   tlbimp /transform:dispret sourcepath\wgssSTU.dll  /out:wgssSTU.tlb.dll

I have this file wgssSTU.tlb.dll But where I run step 2 to create DLL? I need to create dll for .NET Framework 3.5

Samples here: http://gsdt.wacom.eu/support/STU-SDK-API-Samples.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution.

1) to add VS Command Prompt as external tool:

[How can I add the VS Command Prompt to Visual Studio 2010 C# Express?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4245282/how-can-i-add-the-vs-command-prompt-to-visual-studio-2010-c-sharp-express?lq=1)

2) run command from there.